# RStan Segfault Error

Tags: r, bayesian, rstan

I downloaded the package 'rstan' for doing bayesian work with R.  And I'm getting this error

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x20, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

How do I make rstan work?

Comment: i actually know the answer.  i found it on a google group.  but its a little hard to find.  so im adding it on stackoverflow for others who run into this.

Answer (score 3):

```
install.packages(c("Rcpp", "inline"), type = "source")
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/stan-users/XAlXvXsurdM

Comment: More generally, Rcpp needs to be built with the same compiler as rstan or rstanarm or any other package that links against Rcpp. That may or may not require that you build it yourself from source if you are using Windows or a Mac.